# Retrieve the font-size form page

Tags: css, font-size

I'd like to make sure the font-size of `edit` button of stackoverflow's question:

I checked it in development tool of chrome, but get

```
font-size:100%
font-size;inherit,
```

and some deleted style

[image]

How could I check it in a straightforward way?

Comment: Click on Computed tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the tab "*computed*". There you find everything (including browser styles) in absolute units.